# how to get more than one value with function coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get some query results with coalesce function but when it gives me more than one value it gives an oracle error. These is my query:

```
SELECT COALESCE((select GRPNAME  from CMS_NODGRP where upper(NODEID)=UPPER('unsolwa33')), 'Without_Node') || ' 134unixadmin'  || ' available' FROM DUAL;
```

Someone could help me to gives me the output desire (like these):

```
Without Node 123winadm availabe
Node2 unsolwa33 availabe
Node1 unsolwa33 availabe
Node4 unsolwa33 availabe
```

The error is:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

The table should be:

```
GRPNAME     NODEID
------------------------

GroupA      NodeA
GroupB      NodeA
GroupB      NodeB
GroupC      NodeC
```

I would like that if I make a query and it gives me:

```
NodeD,WithoutNodeID
NodeA, GroupA
NodeA, GroupB
NodeB, GroupB
NodeC, GroupC
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: what's the ORACLE error you're getting?

Comment: I edit the question with the error. The desired results are in the main post

Comment: @absolute333 . . . You need to provide sample data as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the `COALESCE()`, it is the subquery.

This may be what you want:

```
select COALESCE(GRPNAME, 'Without_Node' || ' 134unixadmin')  || ' available'
from CMS_NODGRP
where upper(NODEID) = UPPER('unsolwa33');
```

Comment: it seem not works. With your query if there is no results it gives "no rows selected" when I would like to give me: Without_Node unsolwa33  available

Answer (score 0):

You could instead do:

```
select coalesce(cng.grpname, dummy.col1) || ' 134unixadmin' || ' available' node_availability
from   (select 'Without Node' col1 from dual) dummy
       left outer join (select grpname
                        from   cms_nodgrp
                        where  upper(nodeid) = upper('unsolwa33')) cng on (1=1);
```

This works sort of like a cross join, but in the event that there are no rows returned from the cng subquery, the row from the dummy subquery will always be returned. That way, you can then use coalesce to decide what to output.

N.B. This will return as many rows as are returned by the cng subquery. If you really do want just a single row returned, you could always add `and rownum = 1`, or if you know all the rows will have the same grpname then you could use `DISTINCT` in the select list.

---

And proof that the above query really does work:

For a non-existent nodeid:

```
WITH cms_nodgrp AS (SELECT 'unsolwa33' nodeid, 'abc' grpname FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'unsolwa33' nodeid, 'def' grpname FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'unsolwa44' nodeid, 'egh' grpname FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking some data in your table. See SQL below:
select coalesce(cng.grpname, dummy.col1) || ' 134unixadmin' || ' available' node_availability
from   (select 'Without Node' col1 from dual) dummy
       left outer join (select grpname 
                        from   cms_nodgrp
                        where  upper(nodeid) = upper('not exists')) cng on (1=1);

NODE_AVAILABILITY
-----------------------------------
Without Node 134unixadmin available
```

For an available nodeid:

```
WITH cms_nodgrp AS (SELECT 'unsolwa33' nodeid, 'abc' grpname FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'unsolwa33' nodeid, 'def' grpname FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'unsolwa44' nodeid, 'egh' grpname FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking some data in your table. See SQL below:
select coalesce(cng.grpname, dummy.col1) || ' 134unixadmin' || ' available' node_availability
from   (select 'Without Node' col1 from dual) dummy
       left outer join (select grpname 
                        from   cms_nodgrp
                        where  upper(nodeid) = upper('unsolwa33')) cng on (1=1);

NODE_AVAILABILITY
-----------------------------------
abc 134unixadmin available
def 134unixadmin available
```

Comment: Not works: select coalesce(cng.grpname, dummy.col1) || ' 134unixadmin' || ' available' node_availability
  2  from   (select 'Without Node' col1 from dual) dummy left outer join (select grpname
  3  from   cms_nodgrp where  upper(nodeid) = upper('not exists')) cng on (1=1);

no rows selected

Comment: @absolute333 I've no idea why you get that result; it works for me - I've updated my answer to include a demonstration of the results I get. The fact that the query is using a left outer join means you would at the very least get one row back (with the dummy col1 populated and the cng.grpname null).

Comment: Thanks, for me not works: SQL> Select * from cms_nodgrp where upper(nodeid) = upper('unsolwa33');

no rows selected

Comment: SQL> select coalesce(cng.grpname, dummy.col1) || ' 134unixadmin' || ' available' node_availability
  2  from (select 'Without Node' col1 from dual) dummy left outer join (select grpname from cms_nodgrp where  upper(nodeid) = upper('unsolwa33')) cng on (1=1);

no rows selected

Comment: @absolute333 what do you get when you run `select * from (select 1 id1 from dual) d1 left outer join (select 2 id2 from dual where 1=0) d2 on (1=1);`? You should get a single row with id1 = 1 and id2 is blank. Also, what version of the Oracle database are you using (you can find this by running `select version from v$instance;`)

Comment: SQL> select * from (select 1 id1 from dual) d1 left outer join (select 2 id2 from dual where 1=0) d2 on (1=1);

no rows selected

Comment: SQL> select version from v$instance;

VERSION
-----------------
9.2.0.1.0

Comment: sounds like it's a bug in that version of Oracle then; ANSI join syntax was buggy in earlier versions